# How can I solve model error in php laravel with vue?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, core-ui

I am learning laravel, when running a page I get the following error.
It says that I need a model, but I don't know in which part.
I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$model')
    at Proxy.render (42.js:4852:74)
    at 1.js:1679:80
    at activateCurrentInstance (1.js:1639:16)
    at $options.render (1.js:1679:24)
    at Vue._render (app.js:144739:22)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:145238:22)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:145661:25)
    at Watcher.run (app.js:145736:22)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (app.js:145494:13)
    at Array.<anonymous> (app.js:143165:12)
```

I have my two tables,
"orders"

```
id
created_at
updated_at
poliza_garantia
id_poliza
```

"polizas_garantia"

```
id
created_at
updated_at
orden_id
importe
fecha_activacion
```

A radiogroup appears on a screen that does include a guarantee policy, poliza_garantia = 1 and two fields appear and the data added in those two fields (importe and fecha_activacion) will be saved in the table polizas_garantia

this is my view in vue
Here two fields are enabled if the radiogroup "poliza_garantia" is selected, if "poliza_garantia" is equal to 1 (if selected), the CInputs appear

```
<CCol sm="3"> 
                  <label for="">¿Does it include a warranty policy?</label>
                  <CInputRadioGroup  
                  :options="poliza_garantia_lst"                  
                  :inline=true
                  :checked.sync="v$.orden.poliza_garantia.$model"
                  :invalid-feedback="
                      v$.orden.poliza_garantia.$error
                        ? v$.orden.poliza_garantia.$errors[0].$message
                        : ''
                    "
                    :is-valid="
                      v$.orden.poliza_garantia.$dirty
                        ? !v$.orden.poliza_garantia.$invalid
                        : null
                    "
                  />
                </CCol>
           
                <CCol sm="2" v-if="orden.poliza_garantia == 1">
                  <CInput
                    :value.sync="polizagarantia.importe"
                    :plain="true"
                    label="Importe de poliza de garantia"
                    placeholder="Importe"
                    :invalid-feedback="
                      v$.polizagarantia.importe.$error
                        ? v$.polizagarantia.importe.$errors[0].$message
                        : ''"
                    :is-valid="v$.polizagarantia.importe.$dirty 
                    ? !v$.polizagarantia.importe.$invalid : null"
                  />
                </CCol> 
                <CCol sm="3" v-if="orden.poliza_garantia == 1">
                    <CInput
                      :value.sync="polizagarantia.fecha_activacion"
                      label="Fecha de activacion de la poliza de garantia (Considerando que esta instalado el proyecto)"
                      type="date"
                    >
                    </CInput>
                </CCol>
```

Here are the instances and validations of the vue

```
PolizasGarantia: {
    importe: "",
    fecha_activacion: "",
  },
  Orden: {
    poliza_garantia: "",
    id_poliza: "",
    test_poliza: "",
  }

data() {
    return {
poliza_garantia_lst: [
              { value: 1, label: 'Si'},
              { value: 0, label: 'No'}
            ]}

polizagarantia: {
        importe: "",
        fecha_activacion: "",
      },
      orden:  {
        poliza_garantia: "",
        id_poliza: "",
        test_poliza:"",

validations(){
return{
orden:
id_poliza: {required: requiredIf(() => this.orden.poliza_garantia == 1), $autoDirty: true},

}
}

polizagarantia:{
        importe: {required: requiredIf(() => this.orden.poliza_garantia == 1), numeric, $autoDirty: true},
        fecha_activacion: {required: requiredIf(() => this.orden.poliza_garantia == 1), $autoDirty: true},
      }
```

This is my Controller

```
public function addOrden(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'poliza_garantia' => 'required|min:1|max:30',
            'id_poliza' => 'required|min:1|max:50',
            'test_poliza' => 'max:10',
            'importe' => 'max:15',
            'fecha_activacion' => 'max:15',

        if($request->input("poliza_garantia") == 1 ){
            $polizagarantia = new PolizaGarantia();
            $polizagarantia->importe = $request->input("importe");
            $polizagarantia->fecha_activacion = $request->input("fecha_activacion");
            $polizagarantia->save();

        }  
        $orden = new Orden();
        if($request->input("poliza_garantia") == 1 ){
            $orden->id_poliza = $polizagarantia->id;
        }
        if($request->input("poliza_garantia") == 0){
            $orden->id_poliza = NULL;
        }

        $orden->test_poliza = $request->input("test_poliza"); 
        $orden->poliza_garantia = $request->input("poliza_garantia");
        $orden->id_poliza = $request->input("id_poliza");

        if($request->input("poliza_garantia") == 1 ){
            $polizagarantia->orden_id = $orden->$id;
            $polizagarantia->save();
        }else
        $polizagarantia=null;

         return response()->json(compact('orden','AImayor','polizagarantia'));


    }
```

This is my model

PolizasGarantia.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PolizaGarantia extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'polizas_garantia';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'fecha_activacion'];

    // public function Polizas()
    // {
    //     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Polizas', 'id_poliza');
    // }

    public function Orden()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Orden', 'id_poliza');
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Orden', 'orden_id');

    } 

    public function registerMediaCollections(): void
    {
        $this->addMediaCollection('importe')->singleFile();
        $this->addMediaCollection('fecha_activacion')->singleFile();
    }

    
}
```

The model Orden.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class Orden extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'ordenes';
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at', 'updated_at', 'fecha_inicio', 'fecha_instalacion', 'fecha_fin', 'fecha_deposito'
    ];
    // protected $appends = ['semaforo', 'liquidacion', 'documento', 'fecha_programado', 'fecha_proceso', 'fecha_proceso_cfe', 'fecha_si_asignado', 'fecha_finalizado'];
    protected $appends = ['semaforo'];
    protected $fillable = [];

public function polizagarantia()
    {
      $sub = $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PolizasGarantia', 'orden_id');
      return $sub;
    }
```

1. I tried to solve it but I couldn't

Comment: Your two models appear to both have a `belongsTo` relationship with each other, and that strikes me as a little odd. Is this intentional? What sort of relationship is do they have with one another? One-to-one? One-to-many? Please tell the details.

Comment: The relationship type that the models have is one-to-one, an order can have one guarantee policie

Comment: Then one of those guys should be `->hasOne(...)` and the other should be `->belongsTo(...)`, no? This is as I interpret the [Eloquent Relationship docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

Comment: Well, I think it would be one-to-many, only one order would remain and the records of the guarantee policies would be made, and the guarantee policies would remain stored for the history, in that case I think it would be one to many